# How do I change the DBML (facebook) preferred language?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, fbml

I want to overwrite FB preferred language; as an example:

```
public static string ScriptUrl
{
    get
    {
        string name = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;

            switch (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)
            {
                case "en":
                    //
                    //  Facebook has no en-CA script so we use en-US
                    //
                    name = "en_US";
                    break;
                //case "fr":
                //    name = "fr_CA";
                //    break;

                default:
                    name = name.Replace("-", "_");
                    break;
            }

            return "connect.facebook.net/" + name + "/all.js#xfbml=1";
        }
    }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're on the right track. You can switch the default language for the connect library by replacing the en_US found in `http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js`.